# Copy S3 ambiguous folder structure to simple s3 folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I have S3 folder structure like this
bucket/market/date/business/hr/*.parquet
where only bucket name is fixed and rest all are variable.

I want to merge and copy this data to single folder for each market in date on daily basis.
Eg -

Before bucket structure

```
-bucket
-----usa
----------2020-10-11
-----------------------07
--------------------------1.parquet
--------------------------2.parquet
-----------------------09
--------------------------1.parquet
----------2020-10-12
-----------------------12
--------------------------1.parquet
--------------------------2.parquet
-----------------------22
--------------------------1.parquet
--------------------------2.parquet
--------------------------3.parquet
-----mx
----------2020-10-11
-----------------------17
--------------------------1.parquet
--------------------------2.parquet
-----------------------19
--------------------------1.parquet
```

After processing bucket structure i am looking for with merging all data
bucket/market/date/*.parquet

```
-bucket
-----usa
----------2020-10-11
------------------------1.parquet
----------2020-10-12
------------------------1.parquet
-----mx
----------2020-10-11
------------------------1.parquet
```

What would be the best approach, should i schedule glue job. How can i merge these variables
to understand variables here is example, business can be b1,b2,b3 and hr where parquet data reside 1,2,9 for date-x .
business can be b2,b3 and hr 6,7,10 for date-y
Looking for suggestions.

I have tried reading this data outside AWS and merging and publishing back to S3 but its costly, so looking for alternate option.

Comment: You could write a script that goes through the bucket and moves (actually Copy + Delete) objects. However, I don't understand what you are saying about b1, b2 and date-x. Are you referring to folder names, or data within the files? Perhaps you can edit your question to show some "before and after" examples of what you are wanting to do?

Comment: Thnx updated to before and after structure

Comment: Oh, you actually and to merge the contents of the files, rather than just 'moving' the files? You would need something that can read the existing data and output it in new files. Amazon Athena could probably do it, but you'd need your output files to go into a separate hierarchy, otherwise things will get very confusing.

Comment: can athena Job be scheduled and publish back to S3 ?

Comment: You could schedule an AWS Lambda function to call Athena. Not sure if you can trigger it through AWS Glue.